# How to maximize width of Debug window in Intellij IDEA 2017.1.2 on Windows 10?

Tags: intellij-idea

I cannot find how to change behavior debugger window of IntellJ IDEA 2017.1.2 on Windows 10. I like to use it in unpinned mode, meaning it comes up when build happens (I execute it manually) and when I click on the edited file it goes down. But It does not take full width. It does not go over Project window as you can see in the picture below.
[image]

It works by default as I described on Windows 7. I mean it takes full width. Unfortunately, I cannot provide a screenshot about it. That machine is my workstation.

I cannot find in the documentation how to setup this. I assume it is due to Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's controlled by the **Widescreen tool window layout** option, disable it:

[image: widescreen]